# Objective C How to Add UiLabel to UiScrollWiev

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

HI can I add UiLabel programaticaly to UiScrollWiev because I have read 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html
And I did not find any constructor.
Is there Any way for do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel release];
```

Adding a view happens in the parent (container) view, not the view that is being added.

Also once it's added to the superview, the superview owns it and you should release it.

EDIT: OP asks, "But What happens when I create 10 of them are they placed under each other?"

No. Each UIView subclass (which both UIScrollView and UILabel are) have a `.frame` property, which contains a CGRect struct. That field defines the position and size of the object.

So:

```
UILabel *one = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
UILabel *two = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 200, 30)];
UILabel *three = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 200, 30)];

[myScrollView addSubview:one];
[myScrollView addSubview:two];
[myScrollView addSubview:three];
[one release];
[two release];
[three release];
```

That'll put three UILabels, each of them 200px wide by 30px high on the scroll view, all of them flush against the left side of that view, one right at the top, one 35 px down, one 70 px down.

If the contents of the UIScrollView are bigger than the `.frame` of the UIScrollView, you set a `.contentSize` property (again, a CGRect) that defines the area of the contents that you want to scroll.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast answer.But What happens when I create 10 of them are they placed under each other?